# Reading csv from the second line and creating output

Tags: matlab, output

I want from a csv archive to read only one column. The problem is that I want to read this column from the second line and by using these commands:

```
[d1,tex]= xlsread(filename1);
name=tex(:,4)
```

it's reading from the first line.

Also, I would like to create a matrix that will inclue two columns that have come from commants (equations etc) in my Matlab code.

Answer (score 0):

xlsread is deprecated by MathWorks. Try using readtable in the future.

To your original question, I'm assuming that you want to read everything in the 4th column from the second row onward. If so, your second line is incorrect:

```
name = tex(2:end,4)
```

Without further example code, I can't answer the rest of your question. Add some details and I'll see what I can do.